# What's the most effective way to practise undulation for swimming Butterfly?

Tags: technique, swimming, butterfly

Having swum mainly front crawl for the past few years, I've recently started cross training and working on my other strokes, including butterfly. What's the best way to practise and  improve undulation?

I've already tried using the [British Gas Swimfit](http://www.swimming.org/swimfit/beginning-butterfly-for-competitive/) site videos. They were really useful for breast and backstroke  but I just cant get the hang of it from the Fly instructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found that visualising yourself doing the worm (dance move) gives you the perfect undulations.

Also you may want to try video taping your technique so that you can analyse exactly what isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

[Vertical kicking](http://www.yourswimlog.com/vertical-kicking/) is one great way to get a handle on the undulation aspect of the kick. Trying to improve your undulation on a kickboard can be tough if you have poor low back and hip flexibility (as most people do).

Other tips for making the most of this:

1. Put on some fins if you can't keep your face baove water when
   vertical kicking. Alternate speeds; try overly wide, massive and
   slow kicks. Move on to quicker, slimmer pulsating kicks. By playing
   around with tempo and foot speed you will get a better idea of what
   is most efficient for your kicking motion.